# Is it possible to change Just Cause 2's difficulty?

Tags: just-cause-2

I started at `Hard` difficulty but I would like to move to `Extreme` now. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same feeling, wanting to change it to *Extreme* after a while, since I seem to stay alive in mad gunfights.
I ended up having to just create a new game -- *the game* doesn't allow you to change the difficulty.
But if there is a hack of some sort that does that, I am not aware of it.

P.S. The gunfights get tougher and the AI gets sharper at aiming as you progress in the game, so either think twice about changing difficulty or be prepared and practice your dodging and evasion techniques, and don't spray-and-pray -- make every bullet count; enemies will take on more damage before they fall.

Comment: You can't change the difficulty midway through because then it would make getting the harder level completion achievements really easy to get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but not when you're in the game. You have to put it on a difficulty you're happy with before you get into the game and start your missions.

Comment: This answer starts with "yes" but the rest of it explains that the answer is "no".